# can't change a few lines of text to another language

Tags: multi-language

I created a wordpress website using another language then english.
Everything seems good but there are few lines of text (like search bar, or quick view (I use woocommerce) that are still english.

I did alot of research, but couldnt find a way to translate it. I went into the PHP code, but it was like trying to find a needle in the desert.

Is there any plugin or way that makes it possible to translate the few words that are still english?

I tried to edit the themes POT file, still didn't make any difference.

Thank you.